# How do I count words in a file using the Scanner class?

Tags: java

I need to use the Scanner class to read a file and count how many times a words repeats, but I need to know in which line the word is repeated. Let's say:

```
Jack goes to school
Jane goes to the gym
```

I need to keep a record like this

```
Jack 1
goes 1, 2 
to 1, 2
school 1
Jane 2
the 2
gym 2
```

Any ideas? I'm not familiar with the Scanner class and I know I can use `scanner.next()` to read each word but I don't know how to know if the word is in a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the problem in two steps.  What if you read one line at a time and then start parsing words within the line?  That way you know what line # you are on but don't lose the benefits of parsing using Scanner.

There are a few ways to accomplish part 1.  I'll refrain from posting those in case this is homework.

Answer (score 1):

The Scanner class is carefully designed to conceal this from you. If you want line numbers see LineNumberReader.